# PHP Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in For Loop

Tags: php, for-loop, fatal-error

I got an Error in my For Loop for some reason.
 I just want to go backwards through an array in php.

The Error in my Browser is:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/html/modules/getChat.php on line 18

Line 18 in this Code part line 1:

Here is the Code:

```
for($x = sizeof($result-1); $x > 0; $x--)
{
    echo '<div class="message '.$result[$x].'"> <img src="'.$result[$x].'" /><span class="name">'.$result[$x].'</span>
    <p>'.$result[$x].'</p>
    </div>';
}
```

I hope you can help

Thanks

Comment: Really seems to be `sizeof($result) - 1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot  i fixed it with sizeof($result) - 1 it was a stupid fault too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is an array, and substracting 1 from an array doesn't make any sense. You probably wanted to use this instead:

```
for ($x = sizeof($result) - 1; $x > 0; $x--) // ...
```

And yes, it seems that you unintentionally skip the very first element of your array here. If so, fix the condition (`$x >= 0`) - or just compact the whole loop into `while`:

```
$x = count($result);
while($x--) {
  // output with $result[$x]
}
```

If that's not a bottleneck (and most probably it's not), you better show the real intent of the code with `array_reverse`:

```
 foreach (array_reverse($result) as $el) {
    // output with $el
 }
```

Comment: Also `x > 0` will not use first element of array. Maybe OP intends to do so, but still.